# How to display the letter cut on the bottom in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter app and I'm not sure how to solve this problem. This is what I got for now, and when a user taps a tomato, it generates random quotes. I set the text size as 40, which I think it's too big for the iphone8 emulator, so I can't see the whole quotes if it's longer. I also have an iPad and since it has a bigger screen, I can see the whole quote even if it is longer. This is the picture of my iphone8 simulator. [image]
So far, I only know I should make the font size small, but I think it makes the letter super small when I see the app on iPad (I mean bigger screen). Is there any way to display quotes on iPhone8 with smaller, but for iPad keep the letter size the same as now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution may be to use [FittedBox()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) widget

**From documentation:** Creates a widget that scales and positions its child within itself according to fit

```
FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.fitWidth, child: Text('Hey this is my long text appbar title'))
```